# Github action workflow dispatch inputs empty string with default value

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, pipeline

We would like to add an input called `date_to` which has a placeholder `'2022-05-05T00:00:00.000'` but also allow the user to delete this value and run the code. We would expect that the value is an empty string in this case. But the actual behaviour is that we get the placeholder `'2022-05-05T00:00:00.000'`

```
name: Total hour

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      date_from:
        description: 'Start date'
        required: true
        default: '2022-05-01T00:00:00.000'
      date_to:
        description: 'End date'
        required: false
        default: '2022-05-05T00:00:00.000'

jobs:
  total_hour:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    timeout-minutes: 5
    name: Business hour
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Info
        run: |
          echo "Start date : ${{ github.event.inputs.date_from }}"
          echo "end date : ${{ github.event.inputs.date_to }}"
```

This prints:

```
Start date : 2022-05-01T00:00:00.000
end date : 2022-05-05T00:00:00.000
```

How to make it print, while still showing the placeholder value

```
Start date : 2022-05-01T00:00:00.000
end date :
```

Comment: I fear this is just a limitation. Take a look at this issue where a similar problem around action inputs is discussed: https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/924

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option to add a `if` condition that would print empty when the input value is different than the default one you set?